# Grid layout: cell isn't covering all specified rows

Tags: css, css-grid

Could anyone help me figure out why `.side` isn't covering the third row in the following snippet? (Also, why is the third row so far down it generates a vertical scrollbar?)

I'm sorry to ask what is probably an extremely basic question, this is for a side project and I usually don't do CSS myself, just trying to learn grid as it feels the most natural to me.

Note: I'm guessing `grid-row: 2` is equivalent to `grid-row: 2 / 2` (same for the rest) but I wrote it explicitly just to be 100% sure (makes no difference).

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
}

header {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  background-color: #ccf;
}

.side {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.main {
  grid-row: 2 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
}

footer {
  grid-row: 3 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <header>header</header>
  <div class="side">side</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: grid-row: 1 / 3; says from start of row one to start of row 3, thus covering only 2 rows. 1/4 is the real span you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `n+1` in the `grid-row-end` to place the element until the nth row. Your code need to be like this:

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
}

header {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background-color: #ccf;
}

.side {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.main {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

footer {
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <header>header</header>
  <div class="side">side</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Guess I failed to grasp that from the docs I've read. Still a tiny bit confused since the other answer gives the same results with different values, but I'll figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You just have to change the 3 to a 4 as you want .side to start at the first line (the top of row 1) and end at the fourth line (the bottom of row 3). There is a good resource here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
}

header {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  background-color: #ccf;
}

.side {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.main {
  grid-row: 2 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
}

footer {
  grid-row: 3 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <header>header</header>
  <div class="side">side</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
}
header {
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  background-color: #ccf;
}
.side {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.main {
  grid-row: 2 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
}

footer {
  grid-row: 3 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <header>header</header>
  <div class="side">side</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```